# How to programmatically impose security on a programmatically created MS SQL database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a complete beginner in setting up databases dynamically. I found this code which is used to create a database:

```
String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
    
    str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
     "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
     "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
     "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)" +
     "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
     "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
     "SIZE = 1MB, " +
     "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
     "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
    
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that how should I prevent other applications from accessing the created database without specifying credentials like a username and password? I want to be able to do this programmatically (without using MS SQL Server Studio) since it is deployed along with the C# application on the customer's PC.

Comment: Just making sure... are you aware that sql server would have to be installed on the machine for this code to work?

Comment: *"how should I prevent other applications from accessing the created database"* Presumably these applications all have their own `LOGIN`, and they don't have mapped `USER`s in the `model` database. As a result unless the `LOGIN`s these applications are a `sysadmin` (a ***huge*** security flaw) they wouldn't have access to the database until you gave it to them. Databases aren't put into existing with *everyone* having access; they are put into existence with *no one* having access apart from the creator, any `sysadmin`s, and those who exist in the `model` database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Integrated security uses windows credential to make connection and doesn't need users to type the username and password.  Normally you would create a Windows Group Account (or use Group Policy) for the credentials for the database.  Then only users in the group will have access.  This is easier than to add each user to the credentials and in large companies that use Group Policy there is already an existing Group.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2471b007-9276-43ff-bb7c-cdeba149eb16/how-to-add-a-user-to-a-database-using-c?forum=csharplanguage) for fun a long time ago, from MSDN. Give it a try:

```
public static void AddUsersToDatabase(string databaseserver, string databasename, string usertobeadded)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=" + databaseserver + "; database=" + databasename + "; User ID=WPDOMAIN\\spdev; Integrated Security=SSPI;  password=Password123;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string password = "Password123";
        string sql = "CREATE LOGIN " + usertobeadded + " WITH PASSWORD = '" +
            password + "';  USE " + databasename + "; CREATE USER " + usertobeadded + " FOR LOGIN " + usertobeadded + ";";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```